# align asp textbox control to the right

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I seem to have a problem aligning my textbox control to the right. I want it so First Name, Middle Name & Last Name are on the left but the textbox control is positioned on the right within the Div class border col-sm-4 (33.33% of the screen)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="border row">
    <div class="border col-sm-4"> First Name: <asp:TextBox ID="First_NameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("First_Name") %>' />
    </div>
    <div class="border col-sm-4"> Middle Name: <asp:TextBox ID="Middle_NameTextBox" runat="server"  Text='<%# Bind("Middle_Name") %>' />
    </div>
    <div class="border col-sm-4"> Last Name: <asp:TextBox ID="Last_NameTextBox" runat="server"  Text='<%# Bind("Last_Name") %>' />
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

any help with this would be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Check below changes

1. Wrap the text in a `label` or `span` and add CSS to float left
2. Style the textboxes to float right
3. Add `clear:both` to your CSS class `border`

```css
.container span {
  float: left;
}
.container input[type="text"] {
  float: right
}
.border {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="border row">
    <div class="border col-sm-4"><span>First Name:</span>
      <asp:TextBox ID="First_NameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("First_Name") %>' />
    </div>
    <div class="border col-sm-4"><span>Middle Name:</span>
      <asp:TextBox ID="Middle_NameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Middle_Name") %>' />
    </div>
    <div class="border col-sm-4"><span>Last Name:</span>
      <asp:TextBox ID="Last_NameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Last_Name") %>' />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: The textboxes are getting information from the server hence the runat="server"  Text='<%# Bind("Last_Name") %>'  if I make your changes they will not longer preform the function I want them too.

Comment: im going to need to find another way around this because styling the all the textboxes on the entire website is a big no no. thanks for trying though.